# Find first non-null value scanning rows backwards from current row

Tags: javascript, excel, etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon

### Software

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration 5.4

### Input data & explanation

Input data from a file (simplified, there are more columns):

```
number       name
1009       ProductA
2150       ProductB
3235       ProductC
           ProductD
           ProductE
1234       ProductF
7765       ProductG
4566       ProductH
           ProductI
9907       ProductJ
```

The issue is that I had an `Excel` file format `xlsx` which has the data with merged cells, and for one value of `id` there are `1..n` rows of values.

After converting that file to `csv` values for next rows (other than first) are missing, despite the one column which was not merged (see example `id=3`, `id=6`).

I'm generating a `sequence` using step `Add sequence`, the input is sorted the way it was originally stored in a file.

### Steps to achieve the goal

Basically what I need to do is:

- Find first non-null value that has `sequence_number` less than `current_row.sequence_number`
- Concatenate the value from field `name` to that matching row
- Keep scanning next rows with `sequence_number` higher than the last scanned

As stated before, there can be `1..n` rows of values for such case.

### Expected output

```
number       name
1009       ProductA
2150       ProductB
3235       ProductC; ProductD; ProductE
1234       ProductF
7765       ProductG
4566       ProductH; ProductI
9907       ProductJ
```

### My approach

I believe I'm able to do this in a loop, by using `Analytic Query` and calculating `LAG(1)` and then concatenating the column `name` for one row with null values and discarding other column values from null row - and then doing this in a loop (for like 20 times assuming this is maximum), but I do consider this a bad idea.

There are probably better ways to achieve this result using for example `Java Script` step with scanning the rows backward from current (based on `sequence` number), but I'm unaware of those functions, if they do exist.

How can I achieve this using `Modified Java Script Value` step, or any other efficient way without using a loop for entire content of the file until there are no empty rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introduction

Merged adjacent cells in Excel files are presented on the image below.

[image: Excel file with merged cells]

When opened as a plain text file, it actually creates gaps (data from merged cell is missing) for every row but first that contains the merged cell.

```
number  name
1000/P  um6p1
        um1p2
        um1p3
1500    um2p1
9823    um3p1
83424   um4p1
        um4p2
        um4p3
        um4p4
21390   um5p1
```

While **@bolav** answer addresses the problem, there is a simplier and probably more efficient approach to this issue in `Kettle`.

---

### Approach

- In `Microsoft Excel Input` step go to `Fields` tab and mark **Repeat** option as **Y** for columns that store values in merged cells
- Use `Sort rows` on *number* column because `Group by` step needs the input to be sorted
- `Group by` on field *number* and aggregate *name* with `Concatenate strings separated by` as type and `;` as value

From [Pentaho User Guide](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Freference_excel_input.html):

> **Repeat**  If set to Y, will repeat this value if the field in the next row is empty.

[image: Transformation]

[image: Group by step]

[image: Execution results]

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, I would use `Modified Java Script Value` to save the last seen product and use this for all rows, and then use `Group By` to group the columns.

[image: Transformation]

[image: Javascript]

[image: Group by step]

[image: Output]

Comment: I've adjusted your approach to more columns, done some obvious changes in JS and Grouping steps and it seems to be working. Thank you. Though, I found a simpler solution, but still tested yours to give you the +1 :)

Comment: Feel free to tell about the simpler solution. :)

Comment: Attached another approach as promised. Sorry for the delay :)